# Upload Client for our PHP Application

Tags: php, uploader

our application is developed in php (LAMP) . we have a module where the clients can upload video and share it with other users . so to upload a video im using a java module **jupload** which works well for small size files say 50 MB. but one of my client requirement is to upload a huge video like more than 1 gb.

Can anyone suggest me whether there is any upload client that i can use it for my php application .

Comment: I seriously hope your clients are prepared to run their computers for a good few hours to upload their 1GB files.

Comment: Yes but if there s any client app then there is no need for them to leave our application logged on